# Highest Returned Exec - With Timeout

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global-variables

I have a list of inputs to exec, and want to know which input will set a global variable to the largest value. Currently, my code works as follows:

```
s1 = """
global a
a = 1"""

s2 = """
global a
a = 2"""

inputs = [s1, s2]

maxA = 0
for s in inputs:
    exec(s)
    maxA = max([maxA, a])
print(maxA)
```

Which prints the correct result.

The trouble is that I want to limit the runtime of each call (say 10 seconds, for this example). The method I have found to do this utilizes multiprocessing, such as the following:

```
import multiprocessing

s1 = """
global a
a = 1"""

s2 = """
global a
a = 2"""

inputs = [s1, s2]

maxA = 0
a = 0

def Execute_For_Multiprocessing(s):
    exec(s)
    global maxA
    maxA = max([maxA, a])
    print(maxA)
    return

for s in inputs:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Execute_For_Multiprocessing, args = [s])
    p.start()
    p.join(10)

    if p.is_alive():
        p.terminate()
        p.join()

print(maxA)
```

However, this does not print the correct output. It seems that within multiprocessing, there isn't any way to modify global variables, so even though values are being calculated correctly within Execute_For_Multiprocessing, none of them are stored outside of it.

Does anyone have a workaround for this? It seems like any of the following would solve the problem:

1. A way to modify global variables from within a multiprocessing call
2. A timeout method for function calls that does NOT use multiprocessing
3. An alternative structure for the input strings that would allow us to extract meaningful return values from them.

Comment: I answered your question so as to get the correct result but I have no idea what timing out function calls has to do with your problem of modifying global variables so as to get the correct result via subprocesses. I really don't know what your *ultimate* aim is but whatever it is, I hope your code that you posted is not how you propose to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each process runs in its own address space and consequently has its own copy of global variables that it is updating. Actually, if you are running on a platform that uses *fork* to create new processes (by the way, you are supposed to tag your question with the platform you *are* running on -- this matters), each newly created process starts off with a copy of the address space that the main process had at the time the new process was created but when it modifies anything in that address space, then a new copy is made (copy-on-write semantics). So any changes made to the global variables by the newly created processes will not be reflected back to the main process. However:

If you create a variable in shared memory using [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=value#multiprocessing.Value), for example `a = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0, lock=False)`, then `a` is a reference to a value that points to a location is shared memory that can be accessed by any process in any address space and even if this reference is copied it will still be valid:

```py
import multiprocessing

a = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0, lock=False)
maxA = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0, lock=False)

s1 = """
global a
a.value = 1"""

s2 = """
global a
a.value = 2"""

inputs = [s1, s2]

maxA.value = 0
a.value = 0

def Execute_For_Multiprocessing(s):
    exec(s)
    global maxA
    maxA.value = max(maxA.value, a.value)
    print(maxA.value)
    return

for s in inputs:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Execute_For_Multiprocessing, args = [s])
    p.start()
    p.join()

print(maxA.value)
```

Prints:

```
1
2
2
```

The same program modified for Windows:

```py
import multiprocessing

a = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0, lock=False)
maxA = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0, lock=False)

def Execute_For_Multiprocessing(s):
    exec(s)
    global maxA
    maxA.value = max(maxA.value, a.value)
    print(maxA.value)
    return

# required for Windows:

if __name__ == '__main__':

    s1 = """
global a
a.value = 1"""

    s2 = """
global a
a.value = 2"""

    inputs = [s1, s2]

    maxA.value = 0
    a.value = 0

    for s in inputs:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Execute_For_Multiprocessing, args = [s])
        p.start()
        p.join()

    print(maxA.value)
```

Prints:

```
1
2
0
```

The reason why this does not work for Windows is because Windows launches new processes using the `spawn` method. This means that the new process is initialized by the equivalent of creating a new, empty address space and then launching a new Python interpreter that initializes that address by re-reading in the source program and executing all statements at global scope and only then does it invoke the target function you specified. But in so doing each newly created process is re-executing the statements that create the `multiprocessing.Value` instances and therefore will no longer be referring to the same instances created by the main process.

The solution is to pass to the subprocess the shared memory values created by the main process and have the subprocess initialize global memory with those values:

```py
import multiprocessing


def Execute_For_Multiprocessing(s, v1, v2):
    global maxA, a

    maxA = v1
    a = v2

    exec(s)
    maxA.value = max(maxA.value, a.value)
    print(maxA.value)
    return

# required for Windows:

if __name__ == '__main__':

    s1 = """
global a
a.value = 1"""

    s2 = """
global a
a.value = 2"""

    inputs = [s1, s2]

    a = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0, lock=False)
    maxA = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0, lock=False)
    # These statements are actually unnecessary:
    #maxA.value = 0
    #a.value = 0

    for s in inputs:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Execute_For_Multiprocessing, args = [s, maxA, a])
        p.start()
        p.join()

    print(maxA.value)
```

Prints:

```
1
2
2
```

This code, of course, will also work for platforms that use `fork`, such as Linux.

Comment: Did this answer your question?